# Single.just exception

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I'm stuck to understand why RxJava does not capture my exception and it just crashes. The exception occurs while getting the object to emit.

Here is how my code looks like:

```
TestService testService = new TestService();
Single.just(testService.testGetUser())
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(@NonNull User user) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess(): Launching Home Activity");
          Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "onError()");
        }
      });
```

My TestService class looks like:

```
public class TestService {
public User logInUser(LogInData logInData) throws RuntimeException {
        Log.d(TAG, "logInUser(): Logging user in");
        User user = this.guideMeAroundData.logInUser(logInData);
        return user;
      }
}
```

In my logInUser() method I'm throwing an exception if the user is not valid. This causes my whole Android app to crash.

It looks like this is not the correct way to do it. Could anybody please tell how should I handle an scenario where an exception is thrown while getting the object(s) to be emitted?

Comment: Using try/catch block to process the error instead of throws it.

Comment: Read up on reactive programming. You don't throw exceptions. Also, whenever you ask about "not working", "crashes", "throws exception", post the stacktrace.

Comment: I'm not sure you're right, all the methods to report errors provided by Rxjava define a Throwable in the parameters. For instance: `.onErrorReturn(new Function<Throwable, User>()` and the `public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) ` if you write your code controlling all the exceptions downstream then what kind of exceptions are this methods made for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very common (and baffling) misunderstanding of Java syntax and operations. The code

```
Single.just(testService.testGetUser())
```

is equivalent to

```
User tmp1 = testService.testGetUser();
Single.just(tmp1)
```

where `testGetUser` executes before RxJava even gets involved thus any exception it throws happens before that.

You are probably looking for the

```
Single.fromCallable(() -> testService.testGetUser())
```

or simply define the Retrofit API as `Single<User> logInUser(LogInData data)`.

Comment: Thank you @akarnokd, I knew there was a conceptual problem here. You're correct the VM has to evaluate all the internal expressions before it can pass control to the method.

Comment: By the way, there seems to be this believe that you should control/handle all kind of exceptions in your downstream logic. That idea does not really makes a lot of sense to me. Java's natural way to handle exceptional flows is with Exceptions. I even found best practice tutorials advising to write my code as if it was inside of a gigantic `try-catch(Throwable)`.

Is that really the best way to do it?

Comment: Thank you again, I was doing some test and all my heavy logic was still running on the main UI thread. I was getting a bit frustrated there trying to find out why the service methods where not being executed on a different thread and why they were showing me the same Id as the main UI one.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked exceptions are catched by the RxJava for the most part.

But for checked exceptions you need to provide your own try{}catch(){} 
block.

One example would be -

```
String transform(String input) throws IOException;


Observable.just("Hello!")  
  .map(input -> {
    try {
      return transform(input);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      throw Exceptions.propagate(t);
    }
  })
```

Check out this post for info, it explained very well.

http://blog.danlew.net/2015/12/08/error-handling-in-rxjava/